# Shell scripting: new line command not found

Tags: shell

I am trying to run my shell script from command line lets say;

my script looks like this:

```
#!bin/bash

echo hello
```

When try to run this source ./abcd.sh I get this error.

```
"' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found 
: command not found
hello
"
```

Never seen this before something wrong with having a empty line before "echo hello" ? I was wondering if anyone else encountered something like this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Are you by any chance running on an Ubuntu system, or an Ubuntu derivative?  Just curious...

Answer (score 5):

Along with the first line of your script being a comment, it sounds like your file has DOS line endings, and the carriage return is being treated as the command that isn't found. The error message sounds like something provided by a custom `command_not_found_handle` function (which I believe Ubuntu defines).

Comment: This solved my problem.  I was editing a script on Windows and running on Ubuntu.  I changed line breaks to "unix" mode in my editor, re-saved, and voila -- problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!bin/bash
```

needs to be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or wherever bash is installed (you can locate this by doing `whereis bash`).

Your program should work fine when invoked using bash, i.e., `bash ./abcd.sh`, but when executed directly `./abcd.sh` then the hashbang line does matter because that is how the interpreter is located for the script contained in the executable file.

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo 'hello'`, within quotes. It looks like there is a newline between the `echo` command and `hello` and it is trying to run 'hello' as a command.

The hashbang line should be `#!/bin/bash`, but messing that up won't matter as it will interpret any line that starts with a hash as a comment.

Comment: it works with echo hello too, without any quotes. The only error here is the first line, should be: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: The `#!` line is not (simply) a comment line.  What follows the 'shebang' (the `#!`) is the pathname of the command to execute.  If the script was run by name from the root directory (`/`), it would probably work; elsewhere, it won't unless there's a sub-directory `bin` containing a program `bash` that will execute the rest of the script correctly. This is a kernel-level feature, too. Granted, `bash` itself will treat the first line as a comment (once it's running), but the kernel's already done the interpretation. When the script is run `bash abcd.sh`, the kernel does not do shebang handling.

Answer (score 0):

Run script with debug option to see which line actually is failing:

```
bash -x abcd.sh
```

Note: in this case the [Shebang](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang) line will be treated as a comment, so if the rest of your script is correct, it will execute correctly:

```
$ bash -x abcd.sh
+ echo hello
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file does not have a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
I had the same problem when editing a script under Windows with Notepad++.
make sure to convert to "UTF-8 witout BOM".