# Shell "source" command always has "command not found" on the first line of the imported file

Tags: bash, shell

So this works, but it's weird. I have a shell script reads a config file. Here they are:

Main Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BASE="`dirname $0`"
BASE="`cd ${BASE} && pwd`"
CONFIG="${BASE}/sync.config"
source $CONFIG

echo "$SERVER_HOSTNAME"
```

Config (sync.config)

```
SERVER_HOSTNAME="test-1"
SERVER_DOCROOT="/opt/dir/dir/"
```

When I did this I noticed I would get the following warning when running the script.

> /sync.config: line 1: SERVER_HOSTNAME=test-1: command not found

The first variable was empty, but the second was fine. Just for fun I added a rubbish comment on the first line:

```
#blah
SERVER_HOSTNAME="test-1"
SERVER_DOCROOT="/opt/dir/dir/"
```

The same thing happened, just on line 1. And this time, both vars were available to the script and it ran fine. It just complained about that very first line.

> sync.config: line 1: #blah: command not found

Always the first line. And the rest of the file is fine. Why?

Comment: When you say the same thing happened on line 1, do you mean the line with #blah?

Comment: Sorry yes. I have updated my question to include the message to clarify

Comment: This is certainly very close to, if not duplicative of, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034358/shell-scripting-new-line-command-not-found -- and the BOM issue is among the answers there.

Comment: This is correct. Thank you. I was using PHPStorm editor to write this. I just had to change the editor to Linux/OSX style. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-line-separators.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have an invisible character at the beginning of `sync.config`. Try:

```
 $ head -n1 sync.config | hd
```

For example, you might see:

```
00000000  ef bb bf 23 62 6c 61 68  0a                       |...#blah.|
00000009
```

Which would indicate that the file starts with a UTF-8 BOM (byte order mark).

Comment: Yup thanks for this. I should have mentioned what editor I was using, which was PHPStorm. I changed line separator to Linux/OSX style in the editor and it functioned fine. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-line-separators.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a function which is overriding source.this is how i solved this problem:

`unset -f source $CONFIG`

Comment: The OP already confirmed that the issue was, in fact, wrong file endings as a comment under the existing answer. Please check for already accepted responses!